# How to bind multiple Views to a single ViewModel with Knockout.js

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, knockout.js

I am new to knockout.js and would like to know how to link Multiple Views to a Single ViewModel. I have 3 views in different HTML pages, when I'm in the 3rd page, "onclick" of a button I want to be able to get JSON object of all the 3 Views.

Can anyone please let me know how this can be done using Knockout.js?

Ex: Page 1

```
 <div data-role="page" id="Page1">
<div data-role="header">
    <h1>Simple counter</h1>
</div>
<div data-role="content">
    <p>You have clicked the button <span data-bind="text: count"></span> times.</p>
    <input data-bind="value: YourName">Your Name: </input>
    <input type="button" value="Convert To JSON" data-bind="click: ConvertToJSON" />

</div>
```

Page 2

```
  <div data-role="page" id="Page2">
<div data-role="header">
    <h1>Page2</h1>
</div>
<div data-role="content">
    <p>Hey Hey Hey <span data-bind="text: pagecount2"></span>.</p>  <br />

    This is supposed to be the number from the previous page <span data-bind="text: testspan"></span>
    <input type="button" value="Convert To JSON" data-bind="click: ConvertToJSON2" />
    <script type="text/javascript" >
  var Page2ViewModel = function() { alert("Page2");

     this.pagecount2 = ko.observable(0);
     this.testspan = ko.observable(100);
     this.ConvertToJSON2 = function() {

            var data = ko.toJSON(this); 
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/Person/Save',
                data: data,
                dataType: 'json',
                beforeSend: function() {
                    alert(data);
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    alert(data);
                }
            });
        };
    };

    ko.applyBindings(new Page2ViewModel(), document.getElementById("Page2")); 


    </script>     
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">

</script>
```

when `ConvertToJson2` is clicked I want a JSON object with `{"count": "", "YourName":"", "pagecount2":"", "testspan":""}`

Answer (score 2):

You can bind a DOM element and all its children with:

```
ko.applyBindings(viewModel, domElement);
```

If you have a common parent (DOM element) with all your views, use it as `domElement`.

Otherwise you can `ko.applyBindings` on as many DOM elements as you want with the same viewmodel. Just keep in mind that a DOM element can only be linked to one viewmodel.

Answer (score -1):

Declare all three viewModel as global objects, without putting var in front of them  and they would be available in you code everywhere.

Comment: OP wants to link a *Single Viewmodel*